# Grails events-push plugin fails to respond to events

Tags: javascript, events, grails, plugins, atmosphere

I am trying to move from events-push:1.0.M7 (latest released official version) to events-push:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. To obtain the latter version I cloned the https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push repo and built the plugin locally. The supposed advantage of the later version of the Grails plugin is that it uses newer versions of Atmosphere JavaScript and Java libraries.

In the README file the plugin refers to the GrailsTodos application at https://github.com/smaldini/grailsTodos. However the configuration and the code in the Todos application has nothing in common with the events-push usage information provided in its README file.

Instead, I am trying to use another sample written to demonstrate events-push plugin: https://www.dropbox.com/s/378bqmbu3ad4fnt/GrailsEventsPush.zip. This is an application running in Grails 2.3.7 and using events-push:1.0.M7. It works correctly out of the box with the released version (M7) of the events-push plugin.

Here are the steps I made to make it compile and run with events-push:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (which I installed locally using 'grails maven-install'):

In BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0"
grails.tomcat.nio = true
...
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:events:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

plugins {
    ...
    //compile ":events-push:1.0.M7"
    compile ":events-push:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

In MyEvents.groovy

```
events = {
  'bagsUpdated' namespace: 'browser', browser:true // allows browser push on this topic
}
```

In the EventTestingController:

```
    def updateBags() {
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      event([namespace: 'browser', topic: 'bagsUpdated']) // will trigger registered browsers on 'bagsUpdated' topic
      render "OK"
    }
```

I did not change index.gsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    var grailsEvents = new grails.Events("${createLink(uri:'')}", {transport: "sse"});
    grailsEvents.on('bagsUpdated', function (data) {
        window.console && console.log("GOT bags!");
        $("#waiting").html("Event fired!");
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error.toString());
}

$(function () {
    // Call controller method that emits event when its done
    $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(action:'updateBags')}",

        success: function () {
            console.log("Event should have been already fired...");
        },

        error: function () {
            console.log("Ops something went wrong... ");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The code that worked correctly with 1.0.M7 version of the plugin does not work with 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version. Here is what I see in the Chrome console:

```
defer connecting topic: eventsbus grailsEvents.js:108
defer connecting topic: bagsUpdated grailsEvents.js:108
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/GrailsEventsPush/g-eventsbus/eventsbus?X-Atmosphere-t…sport=polling&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&_=1416503898595". jquery.atmosphere.js:1691
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/GrailsEventsPush/g-eventsbus/eventsbus?X-Atmosphere-t…sport=polling&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&_=1416503898598". jquery.atmosphere.js:1691
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/GrailsEventsPush/eventTesting/updateBags". jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
Event should have been already fired... index:32
```

There are no errors - the browser simply does not get the event fired by the controller, which would produce "GOT bags!" and "Event fired!" statements in the Console.

The application I am trying to upgrade exhibits the same behavior - the server side events do not reach the browser. What am I missing?